# Gemfile check in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm getting the following error when I deploy:

```
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] 
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] You have added to the Gemfile:
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] * source: git://github.com/dgm/declarative_authorization.git (at nested_in)
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] 
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] You have deleted from the Gemfile:
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] * source: git://github.com/dgm/declarative_authorization.git (at nested_in)
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] 
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] You have changed in the Gemfile:
 ** [out :: 209.12.251.103:2222] * declarative_authorization from `git://github.com/dgm/declarative_authorization.git (at nested_in)` to `no specified source`
```

I have rerun bundle install, removed .bundle and rerun... My gemfile and lock file are both checked in.    How do I diagnose this and get it running again?

Comment: working theory... ` :git => 'git://github.com/dgm/declarative_authorization.git', :branch => :combined` the symbol instead of string is different than the other branch specifications in my gemfile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the gem in question and did a bundle update to a new version, and I also change my Gemfile specfication from `:branch => :nested_in` to `:branch => 'combined'`. Something in that managed to unjam the deploy.

I hope this helps if anyone else runs through this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using `github: 'user/repo'` rather than `git: 'git://github.com/user/repo.git'`. Changing to the full git definition fixed the issue for me.